# SQL (PostgreSQL) Pivot based on prefix in values

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, key, prefix

Hello guys (and girls),

I am trying to pivot some values based on a prefix (yes_) in the values of another column to counteract duplications in my master_id.

Original table:

[image]

Preferred outcome:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it using pure sql

```
select
  t.master_id,
  max(case when t.col1 like 'yes%' then t.id else tt.id end) as id_yes,
  max(case when t.col1 not like 'yes%' then t.id else tt.id end) as id_no,
  max(case when t.col1 like 'yes%' then t.col1 else tt.col1 end) as col1_yes,
  max(case when t.col1 not like 'yes%' then t.col1 else tt.col1 end) as col1_no,
  max(case when t.col1 like 'yes%' then t.another_value else tt.another_value end) as another_value_yes  
  max(case when t.col1 not like 'yes%' then t.another_value else tt.another_value end) as another_value_no
from your_table t
  left join your_table tt
    on t.master_id = tt.master_id
   and t.id <> tt.id
group by t.master_id
```